# to show route from current location to moving car destination

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, gps

I am tried showing route from current location to destination using Google map but i want to  show route from moving object to my current location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use nvpolyline something like

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation {

  if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[NVPolylineAnnotation class]]) {

  ```
  return [[[NVPolylineAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation mapView:map] autorelease];
  ```

  }

  return nil;
  }
- (void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {

  // fixes that some marker are behind the polyline
  if ([Appdelegate.CrashUserArray count] > 0)
  {

  for (int i = 0; i < [Appdelegate.CrashUserArray count]; i ++)
  {

  ```
  for (int j = 0; j < [views count]; j++) {

      MKAnnotationView *view = [views objectAtIndex:j];

      if ([view isKindOfClass:[NVPolylineAnnotationView class]])

      {

          [[view superview] sendSubviewToBack:view];

          //view.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"close_button.png"];

          NSString *reqSysVer = @"4.0";

          NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

          if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

          {

              [self updatePolylineAnnotationView];

          }

      }

      else {

          if ([[Appdelegate.CrashUserArray objectAtIndex:i] count] > 0) {

              nextviewbtn=[[UIButton alloc]init];

              nextviewbtn.frame=CGRectMake(10,10,13,22);

              [nextviewbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(OpenUser:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

              nextviewbtn.tag=i;

              [nextviewbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right_arrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{

                  NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [[[Appdelegate.CrashUserArray objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"userphoto_47"]]];

                  if ( data == nil )

                      return;

                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{



                      view.image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];

                      view.rightCalloutAccessoryView=nextviewbtn;

                  });

                  [data release];

              });

          }

      }

  }
  ```

  }

  }

  [mapView setShowsUserLocation:NO];

}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
  {
  SparkFromMapViewController *spark=[[SparkFromMapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SparkFromMapViewController" bundle:nil];

  if ([[Appdelegate.CrashUserDetailArray objectAtIndex:0] count] > 0)
  {
      spark.userdetailarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      spark.userdetailarray=[Appdelegate.CrashUserDetailArray objectAtIndex:0];

  }

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:spark animated:NO];
  [spark release];
  }
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

  NSString *reqSysVer = @"4.0";
  NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
  if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
      [self updatePolylineAnnotationView];
  }
  }
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState {

  if([annotationView isKindOfClass:[RegionAnnotationView class]]) {

  ```
  RegionAnnotationView *regionView = (RegionAnnotationView *)annotationView;

  RegionAnnotation *regionAnnotation = (RegionAnnotation *)regionView.annotation;



  if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateStarting) {

      [regionView removeRadiusOverlay];

      [locationmanager stopMonitoringForRegion:regionAnnotation.region];

  }

  if (oldState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateDragging && newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding) {

      [regionView updateRadiusOverlay];

      NSUserDefaults *def=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

      CLRegion *newRegion = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:regionAnnotation.coordinate radius:1000.0 identifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f", [def floatForKey:@"currentlati"],[def floatForKey:@"currentlongi"]]];

      regionAnnotation.region = newRegion;

      // [locationmanager startMonitoringForRegion:regionAnnotation.region desiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
  }
  ```

  }
  }
  -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)aUserLocation {

  MKCoordinateRegion region;
  MKCoordinateSpan span;
  span.latitudeDelta = 0.005;
  span.longitudeDelta = 0.005;

  oldlocation.latitude = aUserLocation.coordinate.latitude;
  oldlocation.longitude = aUserLocation.coordinate.longitude;
  region.span = span;
  region.center = oldlocation;

  NSArray *points = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.43894 longitude:-73.7396] autorelease],
                         [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.44628 longitude:-73.74119] autorelease],
                         [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.44649 longitude:-73.74106999999999] autorelease],
                         [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.44665999999999 longitude:-73.7409] autorelease],
                         [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.44665999999999 longitude:-73.7409] autorelease],
                         [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.44676 longitude:-73.74073] autorelease],
                         [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.44707999999999 longitude:-73.73990000000001] autorelease],
                         [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.44748 longitude:-73.73856000000001] autorelease],
                         [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.44748 longitude:-73.73856000000001] autorelease],
                         [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.44834 longitude:-73.73581] autorelease],
                         [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.44857999999999 longitude:-73.73475999999999] autorelease],
                         [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.44863000000001 longitude:-73.73417000000001] autorelease],
                         [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.44863000000001 longitude:-73.73300999999999] autorelease],
                         [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.44795 longitude:-73.7008] autorelease],
                         [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.44784 longitude:-73.69398] autorelease],
                         [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.44775 longitude:-73.69092000000001] autorelease],
                         [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.44743999999999 longitude:-73.68584] autorelease],
                         [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.44728 longitude:-73.68165999999999] autorelease],

  ```
                     [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.48679000000001 longitude:-73.59443] autorelease],
                     nil];

  NVPolylineAnnotation *annotation = [[[NVPolylineAnnotation alloc] initWithPoints:points mapView:map] autorelease];


  [map addAnnotation:annotation];


  [loc release];
  [aMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
  NSLog(@"uncomment this when you want to upload record");
  ```

  }
  }

by this method you can draw path on map

Answer (score 2):

I hope you can find a way to implement your functionality from following URL

http://code4app.net/category/mapview